# functional component not re-rendering after setState update hook

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have the below component which I thought would be super simple. The data is passed into a child component that renders a bar chart using charts.js. On the first render everything works fine. However, when I run the 'sort data' function, the data is updated but the child component doesn't re-render. Seen similar problems with class based components but can't find the answer for my case.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Landing = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([
        { year: 2017, value: 50 },
        { year: 2016, value: 60 },
        { year: 2013, value: 50 },
        { year: 2014, value: 80 },
        { year: 2019, value: 70 }

    ]);


    const sortData = () => {
        const newArray = data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.year - b.year })
        setData(newArray);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <BarChart data={data} />
            <button onClick={sortData} > sort data </button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Landing
```

Comment: `.sort` is *in-place*, so React can't detect that anything has changed.

Comment: The answer to 99.9% all SO questions about why react components aren't updating is because people mutate state.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why your component doesn't re-render is because you're directly mutating your state when you use `data.sort` and according to `React` docs, you should

> Never mutate `state` directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `state` as if it were immutable.

- [reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

Since `Array.sort` method is mutable, you should create a copy of `data` and then use `Array.sort` on the new array.

```js
const Landing = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { year: 2017, value: 50 },
    { year: 2016, value: 60 },
    { year: 2013, value: 50 },
    { year: 2014, value: 80 },
    { year: 2019, value: 70 }
  ]);

  const sortData = () => {
    // using `spread operator` to create
    // a copy of the `data` array
    const newArray = [...data].sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.year - b.year;
    });
    setData(newArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <BarChart data={data} />
      <button onClick={sortData}> sort data </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**If an array method mutates the original array, always make a copy of your array before updating your state**.

Have a look here to see which `Array` methods are mutable and which ones are not:

- [doesitmutate.xyz](https://doesitmutate.xyz)

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I couldn’t directly mutate state and thought by using a new array I would be getting around that restriction. Such an easy fix